# SHBrowseForFolder not showing Mapped drives

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-5

Title says it all.

I can Map the drive in Explorer, with "Connect at login" and it does it all at boot.

When I use the SHBrowseForFolder with either the New or Old style, it shows everything but the Mapped drives. It shows all the Networked shared-drives including the UNC for the mapped ones.

Is there an Option section I have not found, or what do I need to do?

Current legacy program needs drive letters only, spits at UNC.

Comment: Why don't you use the vista dialog?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the quick reply, but I don't know what you mean? Where do I find the Vista Dialog? Is it a component?

Comment: Are you running your program elevated (as administrator)? If you map drives as a standard user an elevated program can't see them (and vice versa).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: that would be true if the standard user and admin user are different users. Remember that even admin users do not run elevated when UAC is enabled, but can elevate without having to enter their credentials again. Drive letter mappings are per-user.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There were some versions of Vista which didn't handle mappings correct under UAC consent elevation

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Try it yourself. Map a drive letter in Explorer, then open an elevated command prompt. Drive letter can't be seen. Still happens on Windows 7 (and I'm sure 8 will be the same, I just don't have a Win8 machine here to try it on).

Comment: @JonathanPotter: You are right, and apparently it is by design: [Mapped Network Drives with UAC on Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cjacks/archive/2007/02/19/mapped-network-drives-with-uac-on-windows-vista.aspx): "Because these mapped drives are associated with LUID, and because elevated applications are using a different LUID generated during a separate login event, the elevated application will no longer see any mapped drives for this user."

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Nice link!

Comment: Also noteworthy might be that mapped drives only show if the _BIF_SHAREABLE_ flag is **not** set (see this [MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/95f7b7e8-87fe-4566-bf9a-4f49a6c21811/browseinfo-bifshareable-flag-problem-using-shbrowseforfolder?forum=vcgeneral))

Comment: THANK YOU sigy ! I tried for hours to see why is not working! You made my day!